# Are 6-digit CIP codes available with associated Schools for College Score Card

Tags: data.gov, education, collegescorecard

I'm looking for a specific dataset.

In the *Data Catalog* there is a large set of data through the *College Scorecard*, this data includes a listing of 2-digit CIP codes and the number of offerings by school.

Is there similar data but for more specific CIP codes? Looking to find this same list but split into individual 4 or 6 digit CIP codes.

Essentially looking to have a list of college majors that are available at each school.

Answer (score 1):

Although I am unaware of any existing list, it certainly is possible to create one using the IPEDS Use The Data tool (https://nces.ed.gov/ipeds/use-the-data) which allows for the downloading of the IPEDS Completions survey data, which includes all awards conferred (by CIP and by level) for all 7000+ IPEDS-participating institutions.

Comment: This is what we actually decided to do, but it isn't a 100% complete list because there can be majors that aren't awarded but still are available at schools.